# tag and convert wav files

Tags: 7, files

I want to be able to upload WAV files and input tags such as artist, title, isrc etc. and covert to tagged 320 knit mp3, flac an alac files. There's some drupal 6 modules that do some of this but not for d7 as far as I can see. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The [D6 audio module](https://www.drupal.org/project/audio) could read & write ID3 tags and the [audioconverter](https://www.drupal.org/project/audioconverter) module can convert to Mp3 - while these doesn't fully do what I need it does hint at that it's possible to do this via drupal. Correct?

From what I've understood FFMPEG/SoX/LAME are all ways to handle tasks like this.

I've never written a module myself but wouldn't mind putting in the hard work of learning to do so if anyone can assist with guidance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. Please read the tooltip of downvote button. Can you post effects of your research effort? Also, "Requests for tutorials and other online resources" are [defined as off-topic](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so please don't post questions like "link me a module". You are free to ask "how to something", and answer *may* be a module, but please don't *just* ask for links.

Comment: Cheers, I'll edit and elaborate

Comment: @Mołot. is my edit satisfactory?